# How does the compiler understand which exception to run below?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

```
    try {
        Image image = new Image("MyComputer/Documents/Photos/estambul.jpg");

        try {
            //...

            image.print();

            throw new NullPointerException();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("FINALLY");
            image.close();
            throw new IOException();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println("IO_EXCEPTION");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("THREAD IS CONTINUE");
```

NullPointerException is not thrown here. However, there is no catch block that catches it. It looks like IOException is squashing NullPointerException. What is your comment? I did not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `NullPointerException` is not thrown here.

Actually, it is ... assuming that the code reaches the statement where you explicitly throwing it.

But the thing is that the inner `try` has a `finally` block.  And in the `finally` block you are explicitly throwing an `IOException`.  This is going to replace the original exception.

The behavior is specified in [JLS 14.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2).  The text that governs youw example is:

> *"If execution of the `try` block completes abruptly because of a throw of a value `V`, then there is a choice:*
>
> ...
>
> - *If the `finally` block completes abruptly for reason `S`, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for reason `S` (and the `throw` of value `V` is discarded and forgotten)."*

---

> It looks like `IOException` is squashing `NullPointerException`.

Sort of.  However, we use the informal term *squashing* to refer to the practice of catching and ignoring exceptions.

---

> Then it can only handle one exception at runtime.

That is correct. At any point in time there can be at most one "abrupt termination reason" for each thread.

Comment: Then it can only handle one exception at runtime.
Thanks for your answer